# Чтение и запись (редактирование) БД

Tags: php, html, база-данных

Такой вопрос: есть БД test, в ней таблица lpcms, внутри которой ячейки id, title и content.
Также есть форма такого плана:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="title" value="Значение title у id=1"/>
<input type="text" name="content" value="Значение content у id=1"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Сохранить">
</form>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы внутри форм, а конкретно в value, при заходе в админку были вписаны значения, вытащенные из БД, а при их изменении и нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить" происходила перезапись на новые значения. В таблице только одна строка будет из id, который равен 1. Других ИД не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Помести в value переменные, которые возвращают из бд нужный тебе контент.